# Shelljs: how to cancel async process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, shelljs

Given I do something like:

`shelljs.exec('someLongrunningCommand', {async: true})`

How can I send a SIGINT or otherwise cancel this process in the same script?

Answer (score 4):

You can cancel the process by sending a SIGINT or SIGHUP signal with *subprocess.kill()* methods like this:

```
const shell = require('shelljs');

let process = shell.exec('someLongrunningCommand', { async: true });

// Here you stop the process
process.kill('SIGINT');
```